# Counting all sets with the same Least Common Multiple

Tags: number-theory

My first try to find all sets with LCM=n was this:
i.e. $n=60$

```
k = 0;
n = 60;
For[i = 2, i <= Length[Subsets[Divisors[n]]], i++, 
If[Apply[LCM, Flatten[Take[Subsets[Divisors[n]], {i, i}]]] == n, 
k = k + 1]];
k
```

and it worked for small $n$

then I found the [OEIS series A076078](https://oeis.org/A076078) and there was this more efficient algorithm

```
f[n_] := Block[{d = Divisors[n]}, Plus @@ (MoebiusMu[n/d](2^DivisorSigma[0, d] - 1))]; 
f[60]
```

The problem is that I want $n$ to be a very large number.

In the comments on the OEIS page I found something very useful which I don't understand very well:

> a(n)=1 iff n=1, a(p^k)=2^k, a(p*q)=10; where p & q are unique primes. a(n) cannot equal an odd number >1.
>
> If m has more divisors than n, then a(m) > a(n).
>
> If n is of the form p^r*q^s where p & q are distinct primes and r & s are nonnegative integers then a(n)=2^(rs)*(2^(r+s+1)-2^r-2^s+1).
>
> Also if n=p_1^r_1*p_2^r_2*...*p_k^r_k where p_1,p_2,...,p_k are distinct primes and r_1,r_2,...,r_k are natural numbers then 2^(r_1*r_2*...*r_k)||a(n).

Can somebody explain `2^(r_1*r_2*...*r_k)||a(n)` to me?

Answer (score 2):

Note that your own code could be made *orders of magnitude* faster as follows:

```
Count[LCM @@@ Subsets[Divisors[n]][[2 ;;]], n]
(* Out: 3748 *)
```

For $n=60$, your code takes 4 seconds; the code above takes 6 *milliseconds*. This is still worse than the entirely different (and superior) approach you found on the OEIS page. In the end, in your approach (and mine above), the problem is `Subsets`, which becomes horribly expensive for large $n$.

---

`||` is used here to mean "exactly divides" ([Wikipedia list of math symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols)). $a(n)$ on [that page](https://oeis.org/A076078) is the number of nonempty sets of distinct positive integers that have a least common multiple of $n$, i.e. the number you seek.

So that observation seems to translate to the following: if your integer $n$ can be expressed as a sum of prime powers, like the following $n=p_1^{r_1}+p_2^{r_2}+ \ldots +p_k^{r_k}$, for some primes $p_i$ and positive integers $r_i$, then $2^{(r_1 r_2\ \ldots \ r_k)}$ exactly divides $a(n)$.

How that can be used to calculate $a(n)$ is not immediately apparent to me, but more in general your question deals with the math, and not with *Mathematica* anyway.

Comment: In your penultimate paragraph, do you mean n can be expressed as a *product* of primes powers?